# Asynchronous threads drawing in Bitmaps Delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi, graphics, asynchronous, bitmap

If many asynchronous threads draw in a global TBitmap, it will rise me an error? Should I create my code using a critical section? (From my surf on the internet I found that the TBitmap.Draw is not thread safe)

Another question: If many synchronous threads draw in a global TBitmap and a VCL Timer read asynchronously the content from the TBitmap will this rise me an error?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need a global TBitmap?  I'm guessing a bit, now, but I think you need more than one TBitmap instance.  The instance being rendered by the TTimer should not be the one currently being written by the other threads.

Comment: The trick is, with video rendering, to keep a queue of ready-prepared TBitmaps so that the TTimer can always dequeue one and render it without any syncho. with the other threads that are busy preparing other bitmaps to be queued up.  Synchonization with mutexes, critical sections etc. on one bitmap instance will be messy and perform very poorly, even if you can get it to work correctly.  Multithreaded performance is safer and quicker if you can avoid as much locking/synchro as possible - thave threads work on a different bitmap than the one being rendered.

Comment: @Martin You can't really do video rendering on a `TTimer`. You need something more precise than that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - you can!  Problems only arise if the GUI thread, (and so the TTimer), cannot get enough CPU to keep up with the frame rate. If that is the case, it doesn't really matter what kind of VCL/multimedia timer you use and it's time to move to DirectX etc.

Comment: @Martin Hmm, I'm not convinced. I think you need a real timer.

Comment: ..and the GUI will not be able to keep up if it has to block on syncro like a critical section.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - it's OK if the frame rate is low enough.  Certainly, if I needed 20+ fps, I would not be looking at a straight TTimer - too much inaccuracy.

Comment: If you're doing a lot of this kind of thing or need speed, you might look into www.mitov.com, which provides tools for working with images and video streams.  Highly recommended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your threads are all modifying the same bitmap, you need to serialize all access to that bitmap. That means reading its contents as well as writing to it.

Of course, this assumes that multiple threads drawing to a shared bitmap is the right solution to your problem. Without knowing what your actual problem is, I could not comment on that.

**UPDATE**

You must also use `Lock/Unlock` when drawing to the bitmap because of the issue described in [Remy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14175192/505088). Which should be the accepted answer to this question.

Comment: That's a good option. Another option would be to synchronize to the main thread. What's best depends on various factors.

Comment: @user - If you draw on bitmap's canvas, it has a lock method that use a critical section.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you do need to protect the `TBitmap` from concurrent access across multiple threads.  A critical section is fine for serializing your drawing code, HOWEVER that is not enough by itself!  The main thread caches GDI resources and performs cleanup on them periodically, which will affect your `TBitmap`.  As such, you will ALSO need to `Lock/Unlock()` the `TBitmap.Canvas` whenever drawing/rendering to ensure the VCL does not rip out its resources behind your back.

Comment: I've just come across this issue, somewhat late to the party I know. Yes, `TBitmap` leaks GDI handles if you don't use `Lock/Unlock` if you call any `TBitmap` drawing method from a thread other than the main thread. Even if each bitmap instance is private to the thread. Because of the pesky global resource cache. Pretty nasty really, a truly poor design. My solution is to use a truly threadsafe bitmap from GR32, but that may not be an option for everybody.

Answer (score 1):

Use monitors or semaphores to control your threads when they do changes in your TBitmap Pixels !

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the TThread.Synchronize method instead?

http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TThread_Synchronize@TThread@TThreadMethod.html

According to the doco for TThread class

> Following are issues and recommendations to be aware of when using threads:
>
> Keeping track of too many threads consumes CPU time; the recommended limit is 16 active threads per process on single processor systems.
>
> When multiple threads update the same resources, they must be synchronized to avoid conflicts.
>
> Most methods that access an object and update a form must only be called from within the main thread or use a synchronization object such as TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer.

Comment: I thought that if I use Critical Sections I will improve my performance.

Comment: I am using TRTLCriticalSection;

Comment: I haven't used this class, but if it's anything like a TCriticalSection, then it's all about Acquiring the lock before using the bitmap, then releasing when done (always in a try/finally block).  Assuming that the TBitmap is global, you're probably better off defining a custom class which contains both the TBitmap and the Critical Section and making the instance of the custom class global.  I wouldn't expect it to improve performance (as all those threads need to serialize their access), but the reads/writes will be atomic and reliable.

Comment: The global bitmap is a bad plan - the OP should dump it if at all possible.